# Some translations are not getting translated

Tags: python, django, django-admin, translation, django-i18n

I have this in my admin.py:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @admin.display(description=_('Cases %(year)d') % {'year': previous_year}, ordering='cases_previous_year')
    def previous_year(self, inv_presidency):
        ... some code ...
```

and this in app/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

```
#: case_tracking/gdoi/case_movements/admin.py:313
msgid "Cases %(year)d"
msgstr "قضايا %(year)d"
```

everything is getting translated, except the one mentioned above!!
why is that?

Thanks

Comment: That's indeed not possible like that, since you interpolate directly, it will evaluate to a string when it interprets the `class` for the first time, not when requested.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`, does it make any difference?

Comment: the `previous_year` in the `admin.display` is a variable that has nothing to do with the method named `previous_year` they both just happened to have the same name.

Comment: but that does not matter, even if it was. A `gettext_lazy` object that you interpolate with `%` will immediately translate to the active language, and return a (non-translatable) `str`ing. So the `description` got a simple string, immediately when it is constructed. It is not translated when it lists the actions.

Comment: I even tried to assign it to a variable outside the class as `lang_cases_prev = _2('Cases %(year)d') % {'year': previous_year}` but it didn't work. How to solve this when we need to interpolate with `%`? I can't think of another way, except of finding another translation that does not interpolate `%`.. It's always good to see your replies Willem!